# Where to #include?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my past applications I have been #importing into my *.h files where needed. I have not really thought much about this before as I have not had any problems, but today I spotted something that got me to thinking that maybe I should be #import-ing into my *.m files and using @class where needed in the headers (*.h) Can anyone shine any light on the way its supposed to be done or best practice?

gary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb it is fine to use `@class` in your header file and an `#import` in your .m files. You'll get an error if you do it wrong from the compiler :)

Basically, if you are only making reference to the class you want to use, but not any *specifics* of the class then `@class` is all that is required. It tells the compiler "I'm going to be using this class here - you don't need to know much about it, other than that it is valid". (The compiler then knows to reserve a pointer for it).

If you were going to be referencing any properties/methods within the class, the compiler would start complaining (as it wouldn't have enough information about the class) so in those cases it wants you to import the file (`#import xxx`) in order to provide the class specifics to the compiler.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

In any source file, import only what you need to make that individual file valid for compilation.  @class is also preferable to importing another class's headers, because the less you load the less you compile.